# BASH shell expand arguments with spaces from variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, arguments, spaces

Say I have a variable `$ARGS` which contains the following:

```
file1.txt "second file.txt" file3.txt
```

How can I pass the contents of `$ARGS` as arguments to a command (say `cat $ARGS`, for example), treating `"second file.txt"` as one argument and not splitting it into `"second` and `file.txt"`?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass arguments to any command exactly as they are stored in a variable (read from a text file, but I don't think that's pertinent).

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use a variable; use an array: `ARGS=( "file1.txt" "second file.txt" "file3.txt" )` and then pass it around: `"${ARGS[@]}"`.

Comment: If the settings are in a text file and the separator between arguments is a space, I don't see why you regard the behavior you are seeing as incorrect.  I mean I can see what you would like to do, but then reading space-separated arguments from a text file is probably the wrong solution.  Maybe use some sort of structured file format if your needs are complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to do this without either bash arrays or `eval`: This is one of the few places where the behavior of `xargs` without either `-0` or `-d` extensions (a behavior which mostly creates bugs) is actually useful.

```
# this will print each argument on a different line
# ...note that it breaks with arguments containing literal newlines!
xargs printf '%s\n' <<<"$ARGS"
```

...or...

```
# this will emit arguments in a NUL-delimited stream
xargs printf '%s\0' <<<"$ARGS"

# in bash 4.4, you can read this into an array like so:
readarray -t -d '' args < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <<<"$ARGS")
yourprog "${args[@]}" # actually run your programs

# in bash 3.x or newer, it's just a bit longer:
args=( );
while IFS= read -r -d '' arg; do
    args+=( "$arg" )
done < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <<<"$ARGS")
yourprog "${args[@]}" # actually run your program

# in POSIX sh, you can't safely handle arguments with literal newlines
# ...but, barring that, can do it like this:
set --
while IFS= read -r arg; do
    set -- "$@" "$arg"
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$ARGS" | xargs printf '%s\n')
yourprog "$@" # actually run your program
```

...or, letting `xargs` itself do the invocation:

```
# this will call yourprog with ARGS given
# ...but -- beware! -- will cause bugs if there are more arguments than will fit on one
# ...command line invocation.
printf '%s\n' "$ARGS" | xargs yourprog
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Jonathan Leffler you can do this with an array.

```
my_array=( "file1.txt" "second file.txt" "file3.txt" )
cat "${my_array[1]}"
```

An array's index starts at 0. So if you wanted to `cat` the first file in your array you would use the index number 0. `"${my_array[0]}"`. If you wanted to run your command on all elements, replace the index number with `@` or `*`. For instance instead of `"${my_arryay[0]}"` you would use `"${my_array[@]}"`Make sure you quote the array or it will treat any filename with spaces as separate files.

Alternatively if for some reason quoting the array is a problem, you can set IFS (which stands for Internal Field Separator) to equal a newline. If you do this, it's a good idea to save the default IFS to a variable before changing it so you can set it back to the way it was once the script completes. For instance:

```
# save IFS to a variable    
old_IFS=${IFS-$' \t\n'}
#set IFS to a newline
IFS='$\n'

# run your script
my_array=( "file1.txt" "second file.txt" "file3.txt" )
cat ${my_array[1]}

# restore IFS to its default state
IFS=$old_IFS
```

It's probably better to not mess around with IFS unless you have to. If you can quote the array to make your script work then you should do that.

For a much more in depth look into using arrays see:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005

Comment: Please consider using a source other than the ABS -- it's [rather notorious](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs) for using bad practices in its examples. There's [the bash-hackers page on arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays), [the BashGuide on arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays), and [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005).

Comment: Also, if your original IFS value is unset, the `old_IFS` shuffle you're doing here won't behave as you intend. Consider `old_IFS=${IFS-$' \t\n'}`, to store the default value in `old_IFS` if the original value is unset (as opposed to set-to-an-empty-string).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have updated the answer.

Comment: BTW, `IFS='$\n'` is very different from `IFS=$'\n'`. In the former case, your `IFS` is three characters, `$`, the backslash, and `n`. In the latter, it's one character, a literal newline.

Comment: I stumbled here, found this answer, and was able to solve a long-standing bug. Why the myriad of other SO answers which change `IFS` don't caution about it restoring is baffling. Thankyou!

Comment: @AntiEarth, not so baffling: the better-written subset of answers on Stack Overflow that advise changing IFS use formulations that don't _require_ you to restore the old value. For example, in `IFS=, read -r -a array <<<"$string_with_commas"` doesn't _require_ you to restore `IFS`, because the change is scoped to the `read` command and automatically undone when that command is complete.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Without `bash`*isms*, plain shell code might need an `eval`:

```
# make three temp files and list them.
cd /tmp ;  echo ho > ho ; echo ho ho > "ho ho" ; echo ha > ha ; 
A='ho "ho ho" ha' ; eval grep -n '.' $A
```

Output:

```
ho:1:ho
ho ho:1:ho ho
ha:1:ha
```

---

Note that `eval` is powerful, and [if not used responsibly can lead to mischief](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)...