# How can I feed this long line of arguments to an executable?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command, quotations

**Arguments file**

On `args.txt`, there are long series of arguments for different call of an executable. Each line contain the arguments for a single call of the executable. One line of `args.txt` looks like

```
2 1 -A 7 -B true -C 0.0035 -D /path/to/somewhere ....
```

The line start by `2 1` as the first two arguments to be given to the executable are "unnamed" (do not come with a flag).

**First try**

I first tried

```
i=5
./myexec `sed "${i}q;d" args.txt`
```

it works most of the time. However, for some lines, the arguments are too long and I receive `Error: Command Line Too long` as I am overpassing `getconf ARG_MAX`. Note the software does not allow for specifying arguments other than through the command line.

**Second try**

So I tried

```
sed "${i}q;d" args.txt | xargs ./myexec
```

This second try causes the executable to return nothing.

**Questions**

- Am I doing something wrong with `sed "${i}q;d" args.txt | xargs ./myexec`?
- Once I fix the second try, will I encounter the same issue (`Command Line Too long`) as for the first try?
- Could there be a quotation issue which causes `./myexec` to consider the long string as a single argument or something similar?
- Would you suggest me trying another way of feeding the arguments to `myexec`?

**FYI**

I am on `Mac OS X 10.11.3` with `Terminal 2.6.1`

Comment: If it's too long to fit into `ARG_MAX`, it'll still be too long when you're using `xargs` -- xargs will just split it into multiple invocations of your executable, each of them given only a subset of the arguments you want (and thus, neither being correct).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh...ok. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Audit your set of defined environment variables, and unset any you can do without -- they use the same pool of space used for command-line arguments. Also adding an answer.

Comment: ...otherwise, it's a matter of looking at whether the command you're running allows a configuration file or similar alternate source of options/arguments/&c. to be specified.

Comment: BTW, using `sed` here is quite inefficient. Is there a reason you aren't following the practices given in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)?

Comment: ...also, you're going to hit the bugs discussed in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) if you're dealing with arguments containing whitespace, quotes, etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585662/bash-shell-expand-arguments-with-spaces-from-variable

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I am using `sed` because the process will be happening in parallel. There will be a file of commands of the kind `sed "${i}q;d" args.txt | xargs ./exec` that will be given to GNU parallel (parallel :::: commands.sh).

Comment: I don't see how doing things in parallel justifies the inefficiency of running `sed` once per line. `while IFS= read -r line; do something_with "$line" & done` will run every line's command in parallel while following BashFAQ #1.

Comment: Similarly, GNU parallel itself can run a subprocess for each line of an input file (not that I advise its use, ever, for anything -- but then, that's largely me having an allergy to perl).

Comment: Sure, that's right....I am just used to parallel and I don't know how to limit the memory used or the number of cores used with the standard `&`. Solution probably exist though. Time for the executation of `sed` is quite negligible in comparison to the time that `exec` will take. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Honestly, there are things parallel does that aren't easy to do without it -- I'm just deeply suspicious because it's very dense code, and I don't like trusting things to be correct when they have a lot of potentially-conflicting options without the interactions between them clearly specified. If it did fewer things, I might trust it more. :)

Comment: How long is the argument list? `ARG_MAX` is 262K on OS X. What are you doing that needs more arguments than this?

Comment: @Remi.b, ...btw, since `exec` is a shell builtin, you might find a different name to act as a standin for your unnamed command, just to reduce potential reader confusion.

Comment: @Barmar I am performing population genetics simulations and am in need to specify details of the genetic map for the simulation. The argument list is really that long, it is not a mistake such as an unwished brace expansion that causing this error.

Comment: @Remi.b, ...and this popular software, written with the expectation of really long command lines, doesn't let you specify arguments in any way not subject to such a limitation? I'd call that a bug.

Comment: Is there any way you can change the application to get the information from a file or standard input instead of from command line arguments?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks I fixed the confusing use of the term `exec`.

Comment: No, the software does not allow for another way to specify the arguments unfortunately.

Comment: Really, the approach I would take at this point is to build a patch (allowing an alternate input source) and file it with the maintainer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can I ask you to explain what does `build a patch and file it with the maintainer` mean in simple terms?

Comment: @Remi.b, roughly: figure out how the genetics program you're running needs to be changed to allow an alternate configuration specification, make that change, and tell the people who wrote that software it how you did so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ARG_MAX` is an operating-system constraint on the combined size of command-line arguments and environment variables.

Because it's an operating-system-enforced constraint, *you can't bypass it without operating-system-level changes*. `xargs` will split your code into multiple invocations, but each invocation is given only a subset of the arguments desired.

What you can do then, if you can't decrease the length of your argument list (and the program you're running can't read configuration by any means other than the command line), is unset any environment variables you don't need.

---

If you'd rather fail outright when your command-line argument list is too long to correctly execute, rather than (as `xargs` does) run two or more invocations each with a subset of the arguments given, I would suggest the following code be used for each line:

```
args=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' arg; do
  args+=( "$arg")
done < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <<<"$line")

./yourprog "${args[@]}"
```